# DllNotFoundException when using DllImport in C# on simple C shared object file

Tags: c#, c, mono, dllimport

I am trying to run C code from C#, but I get a DllNotFoundException even though the file is there. I have a C file "test.c" with the following code:

```
int test(int a) {
    return a + 10;
}
```

I compile this into a shared object library with the command:

```
gcc test.c -c -shared -fPIC -o libtest.so
```

This file gets added to the project, and I have set it's settings to "copy always", so that it is in the build directive. The C# code looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace CTest {
    class Program {
        [DllImport("test")]
        public static extern int test(int i);

        public static void Main(string[] args) {
            Console.WriteLine(test(1));
        }
    }
}
```

I am running it on linux with Mono and framework target version v4.7.2. I get the following error:

```
Unhandled Exception:
System.DllNotFoundException: test
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) CWrapperTestFramework.Program.test(int)
  at CWrapperTestFramework.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in <827de23517bb4c0eb7fed2eff92099aa>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.DllNotFoundException: test
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) CWrapperTestFramework.Program.test(int)
  at CWrapperTestFramework.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00001] in <827de23517bb4c0eb7fed2eff92099aa>:0
```

I have tried importing "libtest.so" too and all other sorts of ways. Using `File.Exists("libtest.so")` returns true, indicating that it can find the file on runtime in the directory.

Comment: Try changing the filename from libtest.so to "test.dll" because that's what you're importing in your C# project.

Comment: @Nina This doesn't work either. Wouldn't it imply a windows shared object file?

Comment: When you say that renaming the library to *.dll" doesn't work either, are you still getting a `DllNotFound` exception, or does it change to `EntryPointNotFound` ?

Comment: It is still a DllNotFound

Comment: See this [page](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/advanced/pinvoke/#library-handling) that describes native interop on Mono

Comment: I had missed the 'Troubleshooting' section when I read trough it first, which helped me understand the problem. I will create an answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Running the executable with

```
$ MONO_LOG_LEVEL="debug" MONO_LOG_MASK="dll" mono CTest.exe
```

told me that that `only ET_DYN and ET_EXEC can be loaded`. Running

```
readelf -h libtest.so
```

told me that `Type: REL (Relocatable file)`, when it should be `DYN (Shared Object File)`. I though the `-shared` compile option did this, but apparently I had to specify it with `-flinker-output=dyn`. So it has to be compiled like this

```
gcc test.c -o test.o -fPIC -c
gcc test.o -o libtest.so -flinker-output=dyn -shared
```

Comment: That's pretty neat I'm glad you found a solution. Although I remember I've shared libraries built with gcc and loaded from C# which worked just fine. I think it generating an object file first then invoking the linker to produce the dll with -shared flag. Although if you are doing programming on Windows, using Microsoft's compiler and IDE is the way to go.